# C command line arguments to int

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int myatoi(char *str) {
    int i, res = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        res = res * 10 + str[i] - '0';
        return res;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int j;
    char str[] = " i want to get argv[2] value here";
    int val = myatoi(str);
    printf("%d", val);
    if (argc == 3) {
        for (j = 0; j < val; j++) {
            printf("Hello, %s \n", argv[1]);
        }
    } else
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Not Enough Arguments\n");
    } else
    if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Too Many Arguments\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I pass my value of `argv[2]` to `char str[]` so that it converts string to `int` and print the output.

`argv[0]` will be file name, `argv[1]` will be string, `argv[2]` should be `int`

example output: `./hello raju 2`

```
Hello, raju!
Hello, raju!
```

as `argv[2]` is 2 it should print 2 times.

Comment: Lookup how to parse Strings as numbers.

Comment: what's wrong with `int val=myatoi(argv[2]);` ?

Comment: ... and *after* you check `argc` value.

Comment: You overlooked the `0` output from the line `printf("%d",val);`

Comment: just do int val = atoi(argv[2]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass `argv[2]` to `myatoi()` or use a variable:

```
 char *str = argv[2];
 int val=myatoi(str);
```

You are also better off adding an input check *before* using `argv` like:

```
if (argc != 3) {
   printf("Expected 2 args\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Your `myatoi()` suffers the similar problems like the `atoi()` standard function -- lacks the ability to detect and report bad inputs. Consider what happens if `argv[2]` is "xyz123" for example.

Comment: what should i do for check for bad input such as xyz123 @usr

Answer (score 1):

Your function `myatoi` is broken: you should move the `return` statement out of the `for` loop.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int myatoi(const char *str) {
    int i, res = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        res = res * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
    return res;
}
```

Be aware that your function only handles strings composed exclusively on digits. No sign, no spaces no other characters are allowed.  You could use more flexible standard functions such as `atoi` or `strtol` declared in `<stdlib.h>`

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        int val = atoi(argv[2]);
        for (int j = 0; j < val; j++) {
            printf("Hello, %s\n", argv[1]);
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("error: 2 arguments expected\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i should not use built in functions for this program.is any other way of doing it,instead of my code @chqrlie

Comment: @raju: If you cannot use the library function `atoi()`, use the modified `myatoi()` I posted above.